# Counting strings between each 2 columns in a dataframe to find overlaps

Tags: r, string, count

I have a dataframe 'dat' with multiple columns of different "Years" with each having values as "Capital cities".

```
> dat <- read.table ("data.txt", header=T, fill=T)
> dat
     Year1    Year2    Year3    Year4    Year5  Year6
1   Berlin Victoria   Athens   Manama Brussels Vienna
2  Beijing     Lima   Berlin    Cairo   Vienna Asmara
3    Paris     Oslo   Dublin   Dublin  Algiers Athens
4    Tokyo     Rome Victoria Belmopan   Luanda  Paris
5     Oslo   Dublin   London   Moroni     Rome
6     Bern   Asmara   Malabo  Algiers
7   London    Cairo
8   Taipei Brasilia
9    Dhaka
10   Kabul
```

I would like to know the overlaps with each of the 2 combinations of the variables/columns "Years", and I am looking for a result matrix of each combination as follows:

```
Year1   Year1   10
Year1   Year2   1
Year1   Year3   2
Year1   Year4   0
Year1   Year5   0
Year1   Year6   1
Year2   Year1   1
Year2   Year2   8
Year2   Year3   2
Etc……
```

When I do this without the loop, I see that in place where there are spaces, it counts them also (as shown below):

```
> sum (dat$Year1 %in% dat$Year1)
[1] 10
> sum (dat$Year1 %in% dat$Year2)
[1] 1
> sum (dat$Year1 %in% dat$Year3)
[1] 2
> sum (dat$Year1 %in% dat$Year4)
[1] 0
> sum (dat$Year1 %in% dat$Year5)
[1] 0
> sum (dat$Year1 %in% dat$Year6)
[1] 1
> sum (dat$Year2 %in% dat$Year1)
[1] 1
> sum (dat$Year2 %in% dat$Year2)
[1] 10
> sum (dat$Year2 %in% dat$Year3) ## counts spaces
[1] 4
```

Can someone help me with how to loop this and how to make sure that it does not count spaces?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are those missing values `NA` or blank `""`?

Comment: They are just blanks. Because if I include NAs, the count function might consider NAs as well in the count, between any 2 variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `table` of column names of the dataset and the values of the dataset after making the lengths same.  Then, use `crossprod` and change the `matrix` output to 'long' format `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`

```
v1 <- unlist(dat)
i1 <- v1 != ""
out <- as.data.frame.table(tcrossprod(table(colnames(dat)[col(dat)][i1], 
                  v1[i1])))[c(2, 1, 3)]
names(out)[1:2] <- paste0("Var", 1:2)
head(out, 5)
#   Var1  Var2 Freq
#1 Year1 Year1   10
#2 Year1 Year2    1
#3 Year1 Year3    2
#4 Year1 Year4    0
#5 Year1 Year5    0
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Year1 = c("Berlin", "Beijing", "Paris", "Tokyo", 
"Oslo", "Bern", "London", "Taipei", "Dhaka", "Kabul"), Year2 = c("Victoria", 
"Lima", "Oslo", "Rome", "Dublin", "Asmara", "Cairo", "Brasilia", 
"", ""), Year3 = c("Athens", "Berlin", "Dublin", "Victoria", 
"London", "Malabo", "", "", "", ""), Year4 = c("Manama", "Cairo", 
"Dublin", "Belmopan", "Moroni", "Algiers", "", "", "", ""), Year5 = c("Brussels", 
"Vienna", "Algiers", "Luanda", "Rome", "", "", "", "", ""), Year6 = c("Vienna", 
"Asmara", "Athens", "Paris", "", "", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("Year1", 
"Year2", "Year3", "Year4", "Year5", "Year6"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```